# Is it possible to execute a query without writing to the binlog, without the SUPER grant?

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

I have a statement (specifically, an `ALTER USER`) that for my use case I cannot afford to be replicated. In a normal MySQL installation, this is easily achievable with `SET sql_log_bin=0`. Unfortunately, this requires the `SUPER` grant, which is not available on Aurora. Is there some other way to prevent the `ALTER USER` from replicating?

Comment: Without SUPER I believe it's impossible .. The only other way (which requires root privileges) is to remove it from the `my.cnf` -- Run your query(s) and re-insert it into `my.cnf`  You can allso do it by restarting mysql with the `--skip-log-bin` or `--disable-log-bin` flags .. Do your business and then restart it without the flags ..  But again this most liely requires root.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely expect it to be impossible, just wanted to make sure there wasn't some mechanism I wasn't aware of.

Comment: See workarounds in answers to this post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106192/set-sql-log-bin-0-in-rds-mysql-5-6 Basically the answer is "nope, you can't do that with RDS or Aurora."

Comment: @BillKarwin which underpins the point that this is not a programming question snd should be moved over to the dba site.

Comment: Given that the answer seems to be that it's impossible, as I expected, I'll skip the formality of copying this question there.